# Laravel ORM/Query builder how get the next page result/content

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Hi everyone I need help on how to make a query that will return the remaining data by 10 using Laravel pagination.

I have 15 numbers of data on my table, on first request it returns the first 10 data which is correct, but I need to get the remaining 5.

I doing this using ***jquery infinite scroll*** so I'm not showing any pagination or links/urls on my **View**

```
public function index()
{
    $query = Task::whereDate('due', '<', date('Y-m-d'))
                ->where('task_phase_id', '<>', 4)
                ->where('task_status_id', '<>', 9)
                ->paginate(10);
    dd($query);
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: please add your jquery code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you convert `$query` to JSON, you'll have an object with an attribute called `next_page_url` (see the doc [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/pagination#converting-results-to-json)).

It looks like `http://laravel.app?page=2`.

You can then simply use this has your request URL with jQuery.

e.g : When you scroll to your page bottom, call `next_page_url`

Comment: @PenAndPapers if it helped, don't forget to upvote and mark as solved ;)